# Debugging Elasticsearch Plugin Integration Tests using IntelliJ and Gradle

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, intellij-idea, integration-testing

I am building an Elasticsearch plugin based on [this example](https://github.com/spinscale/cookiecutter-elasticsearch-ingest-processor). The plugin uses Gradle for building, testing, integration testing, etc. I want to use IntelliJ to set a breakpoint in an Elasticsearch integration test and debug it. I don't care if I run the Gradle build from within IntelliJ or outside of IntelliJ, but right now in both cases I'm running into issues. I'll describe my setup and the problems below:

First I download and build/test the example project via CLI:

```
$ pip install cookiecutter
$ cookiecutter gh:spinscale/cookiecutter-elasticsearch-ingest-processor
$ # keep all default settings when prompted...
$ gradle build # (also runs the test and integTest tasks)
```

This runs fine and the tests pass. I generate the IntelliJ project using Gradle (`$ gradle idea`) and open it in IntelliJ (shows a green Gradle icon on the directory). I use the default gradle-wrapper option and keep all other defaults when opening.

**First problem:** I open IntelliJ's Gradle window (view > Tool Windows > Gradle), but I don't see any of the Gradle tasks which I know are defined in the project. This doesn't seem to be a huge deal, but it would be nice to have them.

---

Now I want to run the tests within IntelliJ, so I open the tests in `org.elasticsearch.plugin.ingest.awesome.AwesomeProcessorTests`. This class extends the `ESTestCase` class from Elasticsearch but doesn't directly test any Elasticsearch API interaction.

**Second problem:** I run this test class using the little green triangles next to the class name. This fails with the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to install test security manager`.

I figured out I can get around this by editing the run configuration and adding the VM argument `-Dtests.security.manager=false`. Now the simple tests run and pass, and I can also set breakpoints and debug them.

---

Now I want to directly test some Elasticsearch functionality, so I write a new integration test class that extends the class `ESIntegTestCase`. The test should hit the Elasticsearch `_cat/plugins` endpoint and check that the response string is non-empty.

```
public class SimpleIT extends ESIntegTestCase {
    private RestClient restClient;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        this.restClient = getRestClient();
    }
    @Override
    protected Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> nodePlugins() {
        return Collections.singletonList(IngestAwesomePlugin.class);
    }
    public void testPluginInstallation() throws IOException {
        Response response = restClient.performRequest("GET", "_cat/plugins");
        String body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        assertTrue(body.length() > 0);
    }
}
```

When I run this via CLI (`gradle integTest`), the test passes. If I add a purposely-failing assertion (e.g. `assertTrue(body.length() < 0`), then the test fails. So that seems to work.

**Third problem:** When I run the same test from within IntelliJ (little green triangles), I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no hosts provided

    at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([6F620686489164F5:270C27B7060A2BA1]:0)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.<init>(RestClientBuilder.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.builder(RestClient.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.createRestClient(ESIntegTestCase.java:2261)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.createRestClient(ESIntegTestCase.java:2248)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.createRestClient(ESIntegTestCase.java:2242)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.getRestClient(ESIntegTestCase.java:2236)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.ingest.awesome.SimpleIT.setUp(SimpleIT.java:36)
```

This maps to the line where I call `getRestClient()`, meaning IntelliJ is blocking the Gradle/Elasticsearch integration testing setup which otherwise works from the CLI.

FWIW, I can still set a breakpoint on this line and debug the test class in IntelliJ and it will stop at the line.

---

Now I try to run the integration tests via CLI, set a breakpoint in IntelliJ, and use IntelliJ's remote debugger to attach to the tests.

I setup a new "Remote" run configuration, keeping the defaults (transport socket, debugger mode attach, host `localhost`, port 5005). On the "Search sources using module's classpath" option, I've tried all the possible settings.

I set a breakpoint on the `getRestClient()` line, and run Gradle with remote debugging options via CLI:

```
$ GRADLE_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005" gradle integTest
```

**Fourth problem:** As expected, the Gradle process suspends, showing `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`. I start the new remote task in IntelliJ, and then the Gradle process continues running. Unfortunately it runs all the way through and doesn't stop at the breakpoint. The tests still pass.

---

I've searched online extensively for different ways to attach to the Gradle debugger. I've seen many things about disabling the daemon, and I've also tried using `--system-prop` to pass the debug parameters, but nothing solves this problem so far.

Comment: `I open IntelliJ's Gradle window (view > Tool Windows > Gradle), but I don't see any of the Gradle tasks which I know are defined in the project` You should [import project from Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_import) into the IDE as a gradle project.

Comment: I tried this after posting the question. I can now see the tasks, but when I run any of them, I get an error from Gradle basically saying that the JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set to compile Elasticsearch. I'm not at my computer right now so I can't provide the exact error. I've made sure that the project JDK is selected and the simple tests still run fine using IntelliJ directly.